# Powershell Get-AzureADAuditSignInLogs Throttling Limits Workaround?

Tags: powershell, azure-active-directory

I am trying to pull the last 7 days of sign-in logs using Get-AzureADAuditSignInLogs from the AzureADPreview Module 2.0.2.105, however I am being throttled. I've tried using start-sleep within try/catch blocks, but no luck. Any other ideas on how I can get around the throttling limits? (other than using the Graph API which in this case isn't an option)

Error:

```
Fetching data from Azure Active Directory...
Get-AzureADAuditSignInLogs : Error occurred while executing GetAuditSignInLogs
Code: UnknownError
Message: This request is throttled. Please try again after the value specified in the Retry-After header. CorrelationId: e23fd131-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-cbd125f5606b
InnerError:
RequestId: xxxxxxx-97be-4ae7-xxxx-8c7c4781ec0b
DateTimeStamp: Sun, 12 Jun 2022 09:27:04 GMT
HttpStatusCode: 429
HttpStatusDescription:
HttpResponseStatus: Completed
At line:4 char:12
+ $Records = Get-AzureADAuditSignInLogs -Filter "createdDateTime gt $St ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
+ CategoryInfo : NotSpecified: (:) [Get-AzureADAuditSignInLogs], ApiException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.Open.MSGraphBeta.Client.ApiException,Microsoft.Open.MSGraphBeta.PowerShell.GetAuditSignInLogs
```

This is the code:

```
# Fetches the last month's Azure Active Directory sign-in data
CLS; $StartDate = (Get-Date).AddDays(-7); $StartDate = Get-Date($StartDate) -format yyyy-MM-dd  
Write-Host "Fetching data from Azure Active Directory..."
    try {
        $Records = Get-AzureADAuditSignInLogs -Filter "createdDateTime gt $StartDate" -all:$True  
        $Report = [System.Collections.Generic.List[Object]]::new()
            }
    catch {
        Start-Sleep -Seconds 200
        $Records = Get-AzureADAuditSignInLogs -Filter "createdDateTime gt $StartDate" -all:$True  
        $Report = [System.Collections.Generic.List[Object]]::new()
    } 
ForEach ($Rec in $Records) {
    Switch ($Rec.Status.ErrorCode) {
      "0" {$Status = "Success"}
      default {$Status = $Rec.Status.FailureReason}
    }
    $ReportLine = [PSCustomObject] @{
           TimeStamp   = Get-Date($Rec.CreatedDateTime) -format g
           User        = $Rec.UserPrincipalName
           Name        = $Rec.UserDisplayName
           IPAddress   = $Rec.IpAddress
           ClientApp   = $Rec.ClientAppUsed
           Device      = $Rec.DeviceDetail.OperatingSystem
           Location    = $Rec.Location.City + ", " + $Rec.Location.State + ", " + $Rec.Location.CountryOrRegion
           Appname     = $Rec.AppDisplayName
           Resource    = $Rec.ResourceDisplayName
           Status      = $Status
           Correlation = $Rec.CorrelationId
           Interactive = $Rec.IsInteractive }
      $Report.Add($ReportLine) } 
Write-Host $Report.Count "sign-in audit records processed."
```

Answer (score 0):

***I tried to reproduce the same in my environment and got the below results:***

[image]
As I have less sign-in logs, I got the count successfully.

Throttling error occurs if there are too many requests. To [**handle the throttling error**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/throttling#best-practices-to-handle-throttling), you can try the below:

- Try to reduce number of requests by giving **shorter time span**.
- As mentioned in the error message, try using **`Retry-After`** header to resolve the issue.
- By using this header, when throttling occurs it delays and retry the request until it succeeds.

As a workaround, you can include **`Retry-After`**  header in your PowerShell snippet mentioned by Mike-Crowley in this [***GitHub***](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-sdk-powershell/issues/281#issuecomment-908758053) blog.

```
try {$webResponse = Get-AzureADAuditSignInLogs...}
catch {
    $webError = $_.Exception
    $mustRetry = 1
}
if ($mustRetry -and ($webError.Response.StatusCode -eq 429)) {
    $SleepDuration = ($webError.Response.Headers[“Retry-After”])
    Write-Output ("Too many requests. Waiting " + $SleepDuration + " seconds...")        
    sleep ([int32]$SleepDuration + 1) 
    $webResponse = Get-AzureADAuditSignInLogs..
}
```

For more in detail, please **refer** below links:

[Error occurred while executing GetAuditSignInLogs. Message: This - Microsoft Community](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/all/error-occurred-while-executing-getauditsigninlogs/faa39dfc-143c-41e4-8b97-8a3fb92fe163)

[How to handle throttling of Microsoft Graph in PowerShell - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71999165/how-to-handle-throttling-of-microsoft-graph-in-powershell)